# C++ Dependency on local static variable

Tags: c++, static-initialization

My memory allocator is initialized when overloaded new operator is called:

```
MyAllocator* GetAllocator()
{
    static MyAllocator allocator;
    return &allocator;
}

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    return GetAllocator()->Allocate(size);
}
```

When allocator is constructed, it creates logger.
On destructing, it prints out all memory leaks.

```
MyAllocator::MyAllocator()
{
    m_Logger = Logger::Create("Allocator.log");
    m_Logger->Writef("...");
}

MyAllocator::~MyAllocator()
{
    m_Logger->Writef("%u Leak(s) Total", m_LeakCount);
}
```

Because **Logger::Writef** uses local static buffer, I need static mutex.

```
Logger::Writef(const char* fmt, ...)
{
     static char buffer[4096];
     static Mutex mutex;

     mutex.Lock();
     ...
}
```

With this, we get following initialization order:

- GetAllocator::allocator
- Logger::Writef::mutex

Order of destruction is opposite, which gives us:

- Logger::Writef::mutex
- GetAllocator::allocator

And here's the deal, at point when **Logger::Writef** is called from destructor of **MyAllocator**, **Logger::Writef::mutex** is already destructed.

Comment: And your question is now?

Comment: `Logger::Writef::mutex` is a function local static, it will live for the life time of the program.

Comment: Order of destruction of static storage-duration objects is the reverse of the completion of their initialization. If one destructor depends on another you need to make sure that their order of construction is correct.

Comment: @NathanOliver I decompiled my project with IDA (Compiled with visual studio 2022) and compiler adds 'atexit' call for every local static variable, which destroys objects in LIFO order. atexit called first for allocator instance, then for mutex. they're destroyed in opposite order.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well i'm asking how to resolve this dependency issue, I need Logger::Writef::mutex variable to be destructed only if allocator was already destructed.

Comment: @ranstar74 If you call `Writef` in the  constructor of `MyAllocator`, then the destruction order ought to be the other way around. The completion of the constructor calls matters, not the start of the constructor calls.

Comment: @ranstar74 additionally requested information [goes to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75828183/edit), not in comments please!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple.  It's caused by the order of destruction, so all you have to do is change the order of destruction.

As you noted the order of destruction is opposite to the order of construction.  So you need to make sure your logger variables are constructed before your allocator.

You can do this by moving your static logger variables out of function scope and putting them at module scope.  They will be constructed at program startup.  By putting them inside an anonymous namespace they won't be exposed to other modules.

```
namespace
{
     static char buffer[4096];
     static Mutex mutex;
}

Logger::Writef(const char* fmt, ...)
{
     mutex.Lock();
     ...
}
```